# Switching to tty (ctrl + alt + f3) then back (ctrl + alt + f2) kills prior session when two monitors are connected to ThinkPad Ultra Docking Station

Tags: multiple-monitors, thinkpad

Here's a weird issue I've discovered: When I have two monitors connected to the ThinkPad Ultra dock, I get some weird problems.  The only one I've found that always occurs is that switching to a tty session then back to my gui session will always bring me to a new gui session with my old one having been killed.

This problem does NOT happen if I have only one monitor connected to the dock.  I don't know if it is relevant, but the number of possible monitors is three.  The first from the laptop screen, and the two connected monitors.  To reiterate, the problem does not occur if only one monitor is connected to the dock.

Can anyone help with this?  What logs are needed?

Comment: This problem occurred on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by testing a live USB of 18.04.03 and 19.04.  The issues was resolved in 19.04 but NOT the USB of 18.04.03.  I upgraded my machine to 19.04 and the problem was resolved.